# Google Drive API V3 - Push Notifications

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

Since Yesterday morning I'm stuck with a google drive API request.

As explained here : https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/push

I'm trying to subscribe to notifications sending this request :

Url :  https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/changes/watch

```
Header :
Content-type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer my_auth_token

{
"id":"An ID generated",
"type":"web_hook",
"address":"my callback address",
}
```

The response is a code 400 with this body :

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "required",
    "message": "Required parameter: pageToken",
    "locationType": "parameter",
    "location": "pageToken"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Required parameter: pageToken"
 }
}
```

This parameter isn't required according for this subscription request but for this one (same url..) : https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/changes/watch

Am I missing / misunderstanding something or is there a problem with the documentation ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `pageToken` parameter is the token for continuing a previous list request on the next page. This should be set to the value of 'nextPageToken' from the previous response or to the response from the getStartPageToken method, as we see [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/changes/watch).

Therefore, you should pass the `pageToken` as a parameter to your URL:

Url: `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/changes/watch?pageToken=[YOUR_PAGE_TOKEN_NUMBER_HERE]`

for example: `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/changes/watch?pageToken=101`

It might be interesting to use `GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/changes/startPageToken` to gets the starting pageToken for listing and watch future changes. See [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/changes/getStartPageToken)

Comment: Thank you for you response which is perfectly completing Mr.Rebot's one

Comment: Unfortunately I have another problem now.
It always shows me this Unauthorized WebHook callback channel
I'm trying with Postman, and with C Sharp

Answer (score 0):

You might be confused, checking the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/push), if you are making watch requests it should be under this post URL **`https://www.googleapis.com/apiName/apiVersion/resourcePath/watch`** and not **`https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/changes/watch`** which is why you are receiving an error "Required parameter: pageToken".

Here is the full watch request code:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/fileId/watch
Authorization: Bearer auth_token_for_current_user
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "id": "01234567-89ab-cdef-0123456789ab", // Your channel ID.
  "type": "web_hook",
  "address": "https://yourdom.com/notifications", // Your receiving URL.
  ...
  "token": "target=myApp-myFilesChannelDest", // (Optional) Your channel token.
  "expiration": 1426325213000 // (Optional) Your requested channel expiration time.
}
```

Don't forget [register your domain](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/push#registering-your-domain) first. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your response Mr.Rebot. The point is that "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/changes/watch" is describes as usable to watch changes on all files. I was expecting to be notified for any file modified or created.