# How to subscribe to changes on Google Drive using watch

Tags: python, google-drive-api, google-docs-api

I am quite stuck in trying to subscribe to changes on a google drive folder. My python3 code is as follows:

```
SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly'
store = file.Storage('storage.json')

credentials = store.get()
if not credentials or credentials.invalid:
    flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('client_id.json', SCOPES)
    credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, store)

# This starts the authorization process
DRIVE = discovery.build('drive', 'v3', http=credentials.authorize(Http()))

try:
    with open('saved_start_page_token.json') as json_data:
        d = json.load(json_data)
        try:
            saved_start_page_token = d["startPageToken"]
        except KeyError:
            saved_start_page_token = d["newStartPageToken"]
        print("Using saved token: %s" % saved_start_page_token)

except FileNotFoundError:
    response = DRIVE.changes().getStartPageToken().execute()
    with open("saved_start_page_token.json", "w") as token:
        json.dump(response, token)
    saved_start_page_token = response.get('startPageToken')
    print('Start token: %s' % saved_start_page_token)

body = dict()
body["kind"] = "api#channel"
body["id"] = str(uuid.uuid4())  # TODO: do I have to do something with this channel id?
print(body["id"])
body["resourceId"] = 'web_hook'
body["resourceUri"] = 'https://meg-wm-it-change.appspot.com/notifications/'
json_body = json.dumps(body)
print(json_body)

request = DRIVE.changes().watch(pageToken = saved_start_page_token, body=json_body)
response = request.execute()

return response.body
```

Except this throws the error

```
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/changes/watch?pageToken=163958&alt=json returned "entity.resource">
```

Which I can't quite decipher. I'm sure my issue will be not understanding the documentation, (ie, I don't understand whether the params go versus the body of this request, and can't find any code samples) but any help would be appreciated!

Comment: If you've encountered an error status code of 400 with your token, you can check this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50481845/google-drive-api-v3-push-notifications) for the correct param and token usage using `POST https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/fileId/watch`. It also stated that you must [register your domain](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/push#registering) first in the Google API Console.

Comment: I actually looked at that post before writing this one; I still don't understand how to translate that into this error. I am using a page token, as my response indicates, it's the `alt = json returned "entity.resource"` which confuses me. My domain is registered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am going to post the answer I found to my own question in the event that anyone else wanders here:

```
# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.pickle.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']


def auth():

    creds = None
    # The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)

    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server()
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)
    return creds


def subscribe_changes(service):
    channel_id = str(uuid.uuid4())
    body = {
        "id": channel_id,
        "type": "web_hook",
        "address": COOL_REGISTERED_DOMAIN
    }
    response = service.changes().watch(body=body, pageToken = get_page_token(service)).execute()
    ts = response['expiration']
    print(dateparser.parse(ts))
    print(response)
    return channel_id


def main():
    creds = auth()
    service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)
    subscribe_changes(service)
```

Comment: How are you dealing with the maximum 1 day expiration time of the channel that you create when you hit watch API? Are you running a cron to create a new subscription daily and that too for all the files you want to watch?